# Exporting SSRS Matrix report to Word gives undesired custom Page size insetad of Letter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Exporting SSRS Matrix report to Word gives undesired custom Page size instead of Letter size

Even if I reduce the size of the report it changes nothing

And if I choose myself the Letter size will print without issues, it fits the page

How could I fix this?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `body` `width` plus 5 cm (`left margin` plus `right margin`) was interpreted as being too big for `A4` and so was upgraded to the next size larger (`A3`.) I've seen this sort of thing happen with formatting (the infamous `"blank"` pages in the report when viewing in print layout or exported layout) when the paper size is set to be **smaller than the right margin plus the left margin plus the body width**. Seems a lot of people are not even aware that the `body` of the report has its own sizing.  And then there is this statement by [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283105.aspx#Pagination)

> After the report is opened in Word, Word repaginates the entire report
>   again based on the page size. Repagination may cause page breaks to be
>   inserted in locations where you did not intend to add them and, in
>   some instances, may cause the exported report to have two successive
>   page breaks in a row or add blank pages. You can try to change Word's
>   pagination by adjusting the page margins. This renderer supports only
>   logical page breaks.

Comment: Being a matrix does not have a fixed width, in design body width is set to much less than paper size. After I export to Word go to print the page size is 11.5 x 8.5 / landscape still the name is "Custom Page" instead of letter

Comment: what is strange is that it's enough to click on the Custom Page icon in Print screen and it is immediately changing to Letter format w/o even selecting Letter. Looks like a limitation of SSRS, everything looks ok like page size, orientation (landscape) only that it's not able to pick Letter and goes to Custom Page